# Should I need separate virtual environments for every separate Django project

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

Does every Django project needs a separate virtual environment? Can't I use one of my exciting virtual env ? If I can't, then what's the problem?

Comment: Yes.  You can use a single virtual environment for all of your Django projects, just keep each project in a separate directory.

Comment: If they have different dependencies or might have different dependencies later, they should be in a separate environment. I put each of my projects in its own virtual environment and git repo.